# How to reach the clearest lake in the world?

Tags: transportation, routes, nature-and-wildlife, new-zealand, lakes

The clearest natural fresh water lake in the world is [apparently Blue Lake, near Nelson](http://www.amusingplanet.com/2013/06/blue-lake-nelson-new-zealand-clearest.html) in New Zealand.

I'm wondering how one would reach it - the tracks to take, walking times etc - ideally a map and directions would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wikipedia's entry on [this lake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Lake_%28Tasman%29) has detailed information on tracks and lodges. It also provides 6 references with details. Apparently about 700 people visit annually. It is reached as a side trip of [the Travers-Sabine circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travers-Sabine_Circuit).

There is a map [available](http://www.conservation.org.nz/parks-and-recreation/tracks-and-walks/nelson-tasman/nelson-lakes/travers-sabine-circuit/track-description/track-map/). The blue lake is a side trip, estimated to take [7 hours](http://www.conservation.org.nz/parks-and-recreation/tracks-and-walks/nelson-tasman/nelson-lakes/travers-sabine-circuit/track-description/side-trips/).

DISCLAIMER: I haven't been there, all information stated here is fully based on the mentioned Wikipedia entry.